# Converting a std::tuple to a std::set

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, c++14, stdtuple

I am trying to convert a `std::tuple` to a `std::set`. I have the following code

```
template <typename... T>
auto to_set(std::tuple<T...> const &t) {
  return to_set_helper(t, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}

template <typename T, size_t... Is>
auto to_set_helper(T&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  using set_t = typename std::tuple_element<0, 
                      typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
  std::set<set_t> ret;
  ret.insert(std::get<Is>(t))...;
  return ret;
}
```

The compiler complains about unpacking the parameter pack for the line

```
ret.insert(std::get<Is>(t))...;
```

I don't see what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
ret.insert(std::get<Is>(t))...;
```

is not a valid context for parameter pack expansion. Unfortunately. But there are ways to do what you want to do:

There's the standard expander trick:

```
using expander = int[];
expander{0,
    (void(ret.insert(std::get<Is>(t))), 0)...
    };
```

Or you can just rely on the fact that `set` can be constructed with an `initializer_list`:

```
return std::set<ret_t>{std::get<Is>(t)...};
```

(which may need a `static_cast` attached to it to ensure that all the elements give back a `ret_t`)

Comment: Do you know why the original does not work, but the expander does?

Comment: @subzero Because the original is "not a valid context for parameter pack expansion". With the other two, an *initializer-list* **is** a valid context.